# Excel: Downloading file LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto did not succeed

Tags: c#, excel, windows, visual-studio

I'm developing an `Excel` `Add-In` using `Visual Studio 2017`. In the `registry`, I accidentally deleted a folder related to `Excel` `Add-In`s because I had problems with making `Excel` forget about an `Add-In` which has been disabled. Sorry for being vague but I don't remember the exact details and maybe that's not even the cause.

Now I'm always getting an error popup when launching `Excel`:
[image]:

```
Name: 
From: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto did not succeed. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto'. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

I thought that repairing `Office` or `Visual Studio` using the official installers would fix this problem as well but it did not. How can I repair the registry related to this `Add-In` error? Maybe the stack trace helps you figure it out.

Note:
The folder `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0` does not exist but `10.0` and `14.0` as well as one without version number do exist so maybe the installer can be pointed somewhere else?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Try deleting `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA` and `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO` (backup first)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is late, I had the same problem with  `Excel Office 2013` today. I fixed the problem by deleting the `add-in` .

1. Open `Excel` as administrator
2. Create a new document
3. Click on the `developer` tab
4. Click on `COM add-ins`
5. Find the `add-in`, it will help you to know which one as it shows you the `add-in` path

If you need this `add-in`, you will have to reinstall it again.